# Same flight and aircraft with layover, but booked tickets separately

Tags: tickets, india, indigo

I needed to book tickets from point A to C. But the connecting (1 stop, no aircraft change) flight option was too expensive (30 min stop at B). So I booked two tickets in the same aircraft (same airline of course) - one from A to B, then from B to C.

Will I be asked to deboard and board again the same aircraft in that 30-min gap? It's for domestic travel within India.

PS: I'm not bothered about luggage since my family will be travelling in the same plane under a separate PNR and they'll check my luggage in.

I had to go through this separate ticket route because I was initially not sure if I could join them, but by now, ticket prices are too high.

What is the process? Will I get both the boarding passes from A? Or do I have to miss the second leg of the journey just because it was booked separately (30 mins will not be enough to deplane, get another boarding pass and board again the same flight).

Airline in question: Indigo.

Comment: Could you mention which airport is airport B? Some, mostly smaller, airports separate arriving and departing passengers, adding to your time, while others are designed in such a way that you are released into a common departures/arrivals area, making this actually doable if you are able to get your boarding pass beforehand (e.g. mobile or print-at-home boarding pass, I don't know if Indigo offers those).

Comment: The airport B is a relatively very small with only 12 gates. Yes, Indigo does offer print at home boarding passes which I will do. I have also selected the exact same seats for both legs of the journey.

Answer (score 2):

> Will I get both the boarding passes from A?

Maybe. A check-in agent in A CAN issue you a boarding pass, but they can also refuse to do so. I would NOT rely on that. Your best option is to check in online for both flights which you can easily do up to 48 hours before a domestic flight. You can try to get the same seat for each leg at this time.

If you have a boarding pass from B to C, you should be ok. Most likely you will exit the plane with the other A to B passengers, exit into the terminal, turn around and line up directly line up with the new B to C passengers, who are already waiting to board. Scan your 2nd boarding pass when you re-enter the plane and you are good!

In rare cases, exiting passengers will be routed not into the terminal but directly to the baggage claim and exit. If that's the case, it would be very difficult to make the connection, since you would have to go through security again. For a domestic direct connection with a 30 minute turn around that would be unlikely but you won't know for sure until you get there.

> Will I be asked to de board and re board the same aircraft in that 30min gap?

Likely yes. You can also try to have the gate agent in A scan both your boarding passes. If they do, you can remain on the plane, but if not (likely) you will have to get off in B. Your second boarding pass needs to be scanned, and if that doesn't happen in A, it needs to happen in B.

On a connection like this, sometimes they deplane all passengers, sometimes deplaning is optional and sometimes connecting passengers must stay on board. Again, we can't predict with certainty how they will handle this.

Comment: Yes, I can get online boarding passes. I've also booked the exact same seat as per your recommendation. I'm trying to get in touch with the airlines to sort it out. Unable to reach them so far

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar trip, for a different reason: I had bought first a HKG-BKK round trip with Thai, and it turned out that I had to go right away after that to Seoul, and my return flight BKK-HKG happened to continue to ICN. So I then bought another round trip HKG-ICN.

When I arrived at BKK to check in for my flight to ICN, the check-in staff refused to check me in all the way. She said I had to get off, pick up my luggage, check in again, and board again the plane (by which time of course the plane would be already on its way...). She alternated between "Why did you book this way!!!" and "Not my problem, that's what you have to do!".

Having a little experience dealing with unpleasant people in Thailand (90% of which are at the airport, the rest in taxis), I didn't scream, unlike her, I didn't make faces, unlike her, and I didn't budge. Having status with Thai probably helped a little, although who knows. After 30 minutes she relented, and started making phone calls. Strangely enough, or not ;-), she was able to check me in all the way, although my luggage in the end didn't make it (I suspect she did that on purpose to punish me), and was unloaded in HKG anyway: Asiana kindly loaded it on their red-eye and delivered it to my hotel the next morning, for free. A different attitude to customer service altogether.

Anyway this long preamble to say that it might be possible, BUT considering that Indigo is an LCC, you might have to fight for it a little. Come early, and explain your situation calmly. Avoid mentioning the real reason you did this, it wouldn't help your case... You bought a ticket A-B, and then your meeting in B was moved to C, Oops. Additional ticket. Head shake. Sorry ma'am.

Comment: I wonder if check-in agents can see when the tickets were bought, in which case the story doesn’t hold (but I’m not sure it makes a big difference). I wonder which approach is best: online check-in on both flights independently and deal with gate agents or “manual” check-in all the way and deal with the check-in agent.

Comment: @jcaron good point. Not sure check-in staff has access to that but who knows... Online check-in is a possibility since OP will be offloading luggage to family. Especially if passengers have to get off and board again at B, as happens sometimes with (generally) international flights.